# margin-right: -100% leaving huge space in IE8/9 on 1024px wide display

Tags: html, css

I am using Flexslider in Drupal along with Views Slideshow with the Omega 3 theme (html5+960 grid) but I am not sure that matters for this questions.

[On this page](http://test.kreesindustrial.com) in IE8/9 when viewed on a 1024px wide display, it leaves a huge gap on the right. [See this screenshot](http://ubuntuone.com/2sTasFQUv32yzyznTy8WLL).

I am suspecting it is the flexslider js because it adds the negative margin after the page loads.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked to see if IE is viewing the page in compatibility mode when you'd rather it not? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/webpages-look-incorrect-in-Internet-Explorer

Comment: Cant replicate this in ie8 or ie9, works fine...

Comment: It is in normal mode, IE8/IE9 standards. I am testing in a virtual machine, the IEVMS here https://github.com/xdissent/ievms, I wonder if maybe that is the issue? Did you test in 1024 wide?

Comment: IE8 8.0.7601.17514 and IE9 9.0.8112.16421, I have never updated them since I installed the VMs.

Comment: I tested it with the Windows HDD that came with my computer and it is doing the same thing on 1024, so it isn't a VM thing.

Answer (score 0):

Was the flex-control-nav width and positioning. Turns out it was happening on Chrome too, I just thought it was IE since the virtual machine was at that resolution.

The [Outline Block Elements bookmarklet](http://aymanh.com/css-debugging-bookmarklets)is what truly saved the day, and it turns out that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488950/unwanted-white-margin-on-right-side-of-screen-behaves-differently-in-chrome-ff/12498924#12498924) which was mostly the same was the motivation for figuring this out.